# Laravel : API response with pagination parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, dingo-api

I want to pass `pagination parameters` through `POSTMAN` and pass  `sort,order,limits` in my `model` to get query with paginate.? how can i do this? Currently it return error.

Currently my route :
`http://localhost:8000/api/allpost`

My `PostController` function :

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $allPost = Post::allUserPost();
        if($allPost !="" && count($allPost)>0) {
           return  [
                'status_code'     =>     200,
                'message'         =>     "Post retrieved successfully",
                'PostDetails'     =>     $allPost,
            ];  
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message'       => "Post data not found",
                'status_code'   => 403,
            ]);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
         return response()->json([
            'message'       => "Internal server error",
            'status_code'   => 500,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my `POST` model function :

```
 public static function allUserPost(Request $request){

    $sort = $this->parameters->sort();
    $order = $this->parameters->order();
    $limit = $this->parameters->limit();

    $userPost       =  Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit)->get();
                    $userPost_array   = $userPost->toArray();
                    foreach ($userPost_array as $key => $value) {
                        # code...
                        $attributes_arr             =   array_column($userPost_array[$key]['categories'], 'attribute_id');
                        $category_ids               =   Attribute::whereIn("id",$attributes_arr)->pluck('category_id');
                        $category_ids               =   array_unique($category_ids->toArray());
                        $category_details_with_att  =   Post::getCategoryWithAttributeData($attributes_arr,$category_ids);
                        unset($userPost_array[$key]["categories"]);
                        $userPost_array[$key]["categories"] = $category_details_with_att->toArray();
                    }
        return  $userPost_array; 
}
```

Currently it returns error

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Post::allUserPost(), 0 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\IDM\app\Api\V1\Controllers\Front\PostController.php on line 30 and exactly 1 expected

So how can i pass parameters in postmen and whats the solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

First change this line to `$allPost = Post::allUserPost();`

```
$allPost = Post::allUserPost($request);
```

and then change this code

```
$sort = $this->parameters->sort();
$order = $this->parameters->order();
$limit = $this->parameters->limit();
```

To

```
$sort = $request->sort;
$order = $request->order;
$limit  = $request->limit;
```

and then you can pass these paramets in a query string like

```
http://localhost:8000/api/allpost?sort=somesort&order=asc&limit=10
```

Also chage this line

```
$userPost = Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit)->get();
```

to

```
$userPost = Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit);
```

Comment: when i pass only limits and set query for `paginate($limit)` it return error `Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get(), 0 passed in D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\IDM\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pagination\\AbstractPaginator.php on line 577 and at least 1 expected`

Comment: change this line   $userPost       =  Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit)->get();

to     $userPost       =  Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit);

in allUserPost() method

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument when calling the allUserPost function inside the try block.

It should be

```
$allPost = Post::allUserPost($request);
```

and then you can retrieve the parameters from the $request variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line in your code

```
$allPost = Post::allUserPost($request);
```

And then in your function, you have to change your request type. And after that you have to do one more change only use `paginate()` method not with `get()` method.

```
public static function allUserPost(Request $request){

    $sort = $request->sort;
    $order = $request->order;
    $limit = $request->limit;

    $userPost = Post::with(['product','categories','user.userDetails'])->whereStatus("Active")->orderBy($sort, $order)->paginate($limit);
    $userPost_array   = $userPost->toArray();
    foreach ($userPost_array as $key => $value) {
    $attributes_arr =   array_column($userPost_array[$key]['categories'], 'attribute_id');
    $category_ids = Attribute::whereIn("id",$attributes_arr)->pluck('category_id');
    $category_ids = array_unique($category_ids->toArray());
    $category_details_with_att = Post::getCategoryWithAttributeData($attributes_arr,$category_ids);
                        unset($userPost_array[$key]["categories"]);
                        $userPost_array[$key]["categories"] = $category_details_with_att->toArray();
    }
      return  $userPost_array; 
}
```

I hope this will help you.